# How to make a revolving camera in Processing?

Tags: c++, c, camera, processing

```
void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P3D);
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw() {
  cameraRotation();
  background(0);
  lights();
  fill(120,10,120);
  box(40,20,40);
}

void cameraRotation() {
  for (int i=0; i<360; i+=1) {
    camera(80*cos(i), -25, 80*sin(i),
    0,0,0,
    0,1,0);
  }
}
```

I want to have the camera revolve around the central box. My `cameraRotation` method is supposed to move the camera in a circle above the object while always being focused on it.

I get a still image of the box though. I tried setting the frameRate lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Processing uses radians in it's trig functions, so you should translate 0 - 360 into 0 - TWO_PI.

Second, you're changing the camera 360 times every frame. The cameraRotation function shouldn't contain a for loop. You could either increment a variable in the draw loop:

```
int ang = 0;

void setup() {
  ...
}

void draw() {
  cameraRotation(ang);
  ...
  ang+=1;
  if ( ang > 360 ) ang = 0;
}

void cameraRotation( int a ) {
  camera(80*cos(a), -25, 80*sin(a),
  0,0,0,
  0,1,0);
}
```

That incrementing could also be wrapped inside the cameraRotation function.

Or you could use frameCount and a modulo to cycle through numbers.

```
void cameraRotation() {
  int a = frameCount % 360;
  camera(80*cos(a), -25, 80*sin(a),
  0,0,0,
  0,1,0);
}
```

Again, you probably don't want to use integers 0-360 as this rotates very quickly. You probably want to turn these numbers into floats and do some division to make them smaller for a smoother rotation.